# Regex match special character + in python

Tags: python, regex

This is my string

```
relation="da incasso monoporta classe A+ "
```

I need to extract the **A+** (efficiency class)

I must try I list of know values like `(A,A+,A++,A+++,B,C...etc)`

So I do a loop

```
for token in dictionary:
```

An example of token is the A+

But I can't catch the A+ token in my string (the one called relation at the beginning of the question).

I use this function to catch something in the string

```
res=cerca_match(token)(relation)
```

con cerca_match defined as below:

```
def cerca_match(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).findall
```

What I catch is res="A" but the expected output is res="A+"

what's wrong?

*** UPDATE ***

I Need to mod this

```
def cerca_match(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).findall
```

I need to pass the token that must be matched ("A+") in this case

**** UPDATE ****

```
def cerca_match(w):
    return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).findall
```

I need to pass a value to this function... I use this function to catch some simply string

```
\b(classe)\b
\b(monoporta)\b
```

But the function must also work if I pass a token like "A+"

So the regex will be

```
\b(A+)\b
```

But that regex can't catch the A+ inside the relation string.

Comment: please show us the input and the expect output. It is not clear.

Comment: Input is "da incasso monoporta classe A+ " and "A+"

I need to check if A+ is inside "da incasso monoporta classe A+ " with the cerca_match(w) function!

Comment: ok, so it always will have that text in the string, just different grades?

Comment: Argh! One last attempt and then I have to move on! Please give a list of variable inputs and what you expect to match, e.g. "da incasso monoporta classe A+ " matches "A+", da incasso monoporta classe B-" matches "B-
" and "da incasso monoporta classe" matches "classe"? Is it true that this is the last word in the string always?

Comment: No, it could appears in any part of the string

Comment: Without example string, you are asking for a psychic code writing/debugging session. Please include more of them in the question, each of them preferably representative of an [equivalence partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning).

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not going to find `+` as it stands. I have rewritten it with test data [here](https://regex101.com/r/qQ9rX8/). Please let me know what is in the output that you don't want.

```
classe ([\w+-]*)
```

which means that you will replace this in your compile. so

```
def cerca_match(w):
    return re.findall(r'classe ([\w+]*)'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

which means that you must be returning this to a var, e.g.

```
results = circa_match(w)
```

where `results` will have your different matches.

Comment: but how can I pass the token to match in this regex?

Comment: It seems that your regex can't catch the +

Comment: Ok but sometime my token is "A++" but other time is a simple word... with "classe" the method is not generic

Comment: so there might be a token following classe? can you put in examples. To generate a regex you need to fully specify the range of patterns it needs to match. What form will the token take? (A+, B+, C-, B--). My regex meets all of those. What other tokens are there and will they all follow classe or not, which means that your string is going to be different, so show us what they might look like.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

relation="da incasso monoporta classe A+"

print(re.findall("[A-Z]\++|[A-Z]",relation))

>>> ['A+']
```

This one will match `(A,A+,A++,A+++,B,C...etc)`

```
import re

relation="da incasso monoporta classe A+"

def cerca_match(w):
    return re.findall("[A-Z]\++|[A-Z]",w)
```

Comment: I need to edit the def cerca_match(w): function

to also catch the +

Comment: Instead of `re.compile` add the `re.findall` to the function. Or are you seeing you must use `re.compile`?

Comment: In your function I can't pass the token (A++ in this case but in other case is a simply word) to match

Comment: The tokens you're passing, do they intentionally have a space after them. Meaning `A+ ` or is it `A+`?